# Using || in if statements

Tags: php

If a user visits **test.php?number=1** or **test.php?letter=1**, I want them to stay on the page. If they visit **test.php**, I want them to be re-directed.

I have tried to accomplish **the above** using the script below, however the following happens:

- if the user visits **test.php?number=1**, they stay on the page.
- If the user visits **test.php?letter=1**, they are re-directed.

  `if(!isset($_GET['number']) === false || $_GET['letter'] === false) {
  echo '<h1>Hello</h1>';
  }else{
  header('Location: redirect.php');
  exit();
  }`

*Note: the value of number and letter can change! It won't always be 1!*

Comment: `|| $_GET['letter'] === false` Will `$_GET['letter']` ever be `FALSE`? I believe you meant `|| !isset($_GET['letter']) === false` to be true to your previous condition. That's a confusing way of looking at it, though. Simply do: `if ( isset($_GET['number']) || isset($_GET['letter']) ) {` and not a reverse, upside-down check if a false response is false. Just check if it's *set*. Even better, consider empty: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php to check if a value exists in the first place.

Comment: @Marcus By removing `false` from the line of code, the user can now visit the page if `number` or `letter` is empty (e.g test.php?number=)

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `isset()` use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) in this case as an non-existent value does not do you any good, ie. `test.php?number=` with no value entered for *number*. Ditto for *letter*.

The following will check if either *number* or *letter* contain a value, to which the condition will satisfy and `<h1>Hello</h1>` will print. Otherwise, if neither contain a value, you will be redirected.

```
if ( ! empty($_GET['number']) || ! empty($_GET['letter']) ) {
    echo '<h1>Hello</h1>';
}
else {
    header('Location: redirect.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll remember to use `empty()` in the future.

Comment: Both `isset()` and `empty()` have their time and place. From the manual: "*empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false*" which makes more sense to simplify the matter and use `empty()` in your case.